# Unfolding maps how obtain country for point location

Tags: java

I had file with countries from which I obtain features and then do list of simple markers:

```
// Load country polygons and adds them as markers
countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "countries.geo.json");
countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
```

Now I want to check in which country the given point is. So I do cast simple markers in AbstractShapeMarker and then check if isInsideByLocation:

```
for (Marker country: countryMarkers) {
        AbstractShapeMarker cou = (AbstractShapeMarker)country;
        if (cou.isInsideByLocation(place.getLocation())) {
            System.out.println("country!:" + country.getLocation() + "" +country.getProperties().get("name"));
        }
  }
```

This works fine for simple shaped countries, but for countries which is contains several polygons (such as USA for example) this doesn't work.

In the documentation http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/data/MarkerFactory.html said to do marker factory:

```
MarkerFactory markerFactory = new MarkerFactory();
markerFactory.setPolygonClass(MyPolygonMarker.class);
List<Marker> markers = markerFactory.createMarkers(features);
map.addMarkers(markers);
```

But I can't understand how I can create classes so that I obtain only polygon shapes.

Or may this is another method check location position for unfolded maps.

Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are casting the markers to `AbstractShapeMarker`, which only handles single polygon or line marker. No need to cast at all. You simply can use the `map.getHitMarkers(x,y)` or `map.getFirstHitMarker(x,y)` and use that.

```
void mouseMoved() {
  Marker marker = map.getFirstHitMarker(mouseX, mouseY);
  if (marker != null) {
    println(marker.getStringProperty("name"));
  }
}
```

Internally, such markers containing several polygons are `MultiMarker`s, so in case you want to do anything special and need type casting, go with that class.

Comment: Thanks, thagel, but this is not I need for. I need to obtain country name without any map iteration - otherwise I could use country.isInside(arg0, arg1, arg2)..
Name of country is required for other computations..